# Nested Flexbox expanding problems

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a nested flexbox for a website layout. The first flexbox makes sure that 3 items in a column stay the same width and one on top of the other.

The second is where I'm having trouble. I want to have a main box between two sidebars, the main box 3 times bigger than the sidebars. I want this to expand responsively both vertically and horizontally, but I'm not sure how to figure it out as a whole.

[It's meant to look like this](http://www.equinoxrpg.com/aegis/index.html)

[and the result I'm getting is more akin to this](https://codepen.io/tiny-trevor/pen/bWwGgm)

Code excerpts here:

```
   .flexcontainer {
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 1123px;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
}   

.container {
    width: 95vw;
    max-width:1123px;
    min-height: 675px;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-align-items: stretch;
}

.leftcont { 
    border: #00ff00 2px solid;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:175px;
    min-height: 666px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
}

.bodycont {
    border: #00ff00 2px solid;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align:left;
    min-height: 666px;
    min-width: 465px;
    position:absolute;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    flex: 6;
    -webkit-flex: 6;
    -ms-flex: 6;
}

.rightcont {
    border: #00ff00 2px solid;
    text-align:center;
    max-width: 175px;
    min-height: 666px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    right: 0;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
}


#footercont {
    border: #00ff00 2px solid;
    max-width: 95vw;
    min-width: 796px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #00ff00;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    background-image: url(/images/layout/aegis-copyright.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 18.77vw;
    max-width: 86px;
    max-height: 19px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And

```
<div class="flexcontainer">

<header id="header">Header</header>

<div class="container">

<div class="leftcont">

<!--Links-->
     <div id="navigation"></div>
    <span>
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />   
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
      <a href=" ">Link</a><br />  
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
    <a href=" ">Link</a><br />
    </span>

</div><div class="bodycont">

<div id="bodyheader"></div>

<br />
<span class="welcome"> 
Welcome message.</span>
<p>

</div><div class="rightcont"> 

<!--Character-->
      <div id="character"></div>
    <span>

    <a href=" " class=" "><span class="name">First Name Last Name</span></a>
    </span>
    <span>Title</span>

<p>

</div></div>

<footer id="footercont">
<div class="footer"></div>
<span>Copyright</span>
</footer>
</div>
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be amazing and you'd have my eternal thanks!

Comment: BTW in this line  <a href=" "" class=" "><span class="name">First Name Last Name</span></a> you have an extra " in <a href=

Comment: oh thanks! Fixed it now!

Comment: Is this what you want? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKpEPW

Comment: You're using `position: absolute` in a lot of places unnecessarily (which also breaks your flexbox layout as it removes the `position`ed elements from contributing to the flexbox layout). From your CSS, it's evident that you're pretty new to CSS, which is fine, you've got to start somewhere! But I have a advice for people new to CSS - **don't `position` things at all unless you absolutely have to**. `position`ing is tricky concept that will eventually `click` for you, but until then, `position`-ing when you aren't really sure will just end up causing lots of confusion.

Comment: @Michael_B That already looks so much better, thank you!!! I'm only wondering how to make it have gaps between the boxes now?

Comment: @Adam I will definitely heed that advice! It's one of those things that worked previously and I've got stuck on it, but I'll make sure to position less :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove all the absolute positioning. It's not necessary to achieve your layout. Plus, absolutely positioned elements *ignore* flex properties.

Second, you have many unnecessary rules bloating your code. You can safely remove them.

To make elements occupy remaining space in a row use: `flex: 1`.

To create gaps between boxes use `margin`.

[**revised codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmaENo)

Comment: thank you so so much! I'll remember in future to keep my code less cluttered!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the answer: instead of giving the body container a flexbasis of 50% you can give it a flex: 2 whereas the other are flex:1.

```
.leftcont {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
.bodycont {
    /* flex: 0 0 50%; */
    flex: 2;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.rightcont {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use flex-grow property to arrange based on ratios

give the center div

```
flex-grow:3
```

and left and right containers

```
flex-grow:1
```

This should be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow?v=control